# How To get Formatted wysiwyg value on form submission

Tags: bootstrap-wysiwyg

I am using [Mindmup](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/) bootstrap WYSIWYG editor but unable to fetch its formatted text value in js.

```
`
<script>
$('#editor').wysiwyg();  
alert($('#editor').val()); 
</script>
`
```

form submission is working, but the above code does not contain value in alert. (mindmup uses div as a text input instead of text area) ..

Answer (score 1):

First, the Mindmup source is 2 years old. There is a more maintained fork (with reference to why at bottom) here: https://github.com/steveathon/bootstrap-wysiwyg

Second, you should use  $('#editor').cleanHtml() to get the output you want to post/alert.

Third, you seem to immediately create the editor and then ask for it's output instantly.  This isn't sensible, as there is no chance to touch the keyboard and input before you do the alert.  Do something more like this:

```
$('#editor').wysiwyg().on('change', function(){
    console.log('current ' + $('#editor').cleanHtml());
});
```

But really a button would be more ideal, as this is going to write to console for every single keystroke you make.  A button to "Submit to server" could do pull the cleanHtml just once.